# No kivy GUI while using vnc to Raspberry

Tags: python-3.x, opengl, kivy, raspberry-pi3, vnc

I am developing a kivy app on my RaspberryPi 3 to show a gui and it is working well. When I am connected directly to the pi (HDMI) the gui is showing. When I am using VNC, there is no gui showing, just the main screen/desktop of the pi. I can do anything but showing the kivy gui. After searching a long time I know this is a known issue because kivy is using open gl and vnc is not supporting this. I tried a lot of things like using different vnc-software (RealVNC, x11vnc) or using fbcp to copy the frame buffer (https://www.github.com/tasanakorn/rpi-fbcp) or the things from this post (https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=146749) but without any effect.

My running kivy app shows:

```
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, 
img_gif (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.0.dev0, git-0471549, 20180720
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.4.2 (default, Oct 19 2014, 13:31:11) 
[GCC 4.9.1]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: egl_rpi
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL ES 2" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <gl>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'OpenGL ES 2.0'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Broadcom'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'VideoCore IV HW'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 2, 0
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'OpenGL ES GLSL ES 1.00'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <2048>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <8>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not     docked
[INFO   ] [KivyMD      ] KivyMD version: 0.1.2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
```

Has anyone a solution for this problem? I mean it should be a well known problem because in my opinion it would be very useful to show kivy apps to screens over vnc!!

**EDIT:**
I solved the problem. Via RealVNC in Experimental Mode (Settings) it is possible to show the kivy app to remote pc. Unfortunately it's very laggy.

Comment: RealVNC does not support OpenGL ES 2, only supports xcb